# issues with Laravel9 Search form

Tags: mysql, laravel, forms, search

I am trying  to add a search form to my application. I thought I had everything right, but Laravel keeps on telling undefined $users in the view.

The Form Below

```
          <form action="{{URL::to('/students')}}" method="post">
                     @csrf
                     <div class="my-3">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="search" name="search" value="{{old('search')}}" class="border border-dark form-control" placeholder="Enter Search Term">
                            <div class="input-group-text">
                               <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Search Students">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="my-2 text-center">
                            <span class="text-danger">@error('search'){{$message}}@enderror</span>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                    </form>
```

UsersController

```
public function search(Request $request){
        $request->validate([
         'search' => 'required',
        ]);

        $query = Students::SELECT('*')
            ->where('name','LIKE','%'.$request->search.'%')
            ->orWhere('email','LIKE','%'.$request->search.'%')
            ->orWhere('department','LIKE','%'.$request->search.'%')
            ->orWhere('course','LIKE','%'.$request->search.'%')
            ->get();
            return view('students',['users' => $query]);
     }
```

Routes

```
Route::get('/students',function(){
  return view('students');
}

Route::post('/students',[UsersController::class,'search']);
```

Inside Students View at views/students.blade.php

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Student ID</th>
                    <th>Stdent Name</th>
                    <th>Student Email</th>
                    <th>Student Department</th>
                    <th>Student Course</th>
                    <th>Actions</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach ($users as $user)
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{$user->id}}</td>
                        <td>{{$user->name}}</td>
                        <td>{{$user->email}}</td>
                        <td>{{$user->department}}</td>
                        <td>{{$user->course}}</td>
                        <td>
            </tr>
       </tbody>
   </table>
```

It tells me that $users undefined

Can somebody help me solve this issue?

Comment: On your `post` or your `get` route? They both use the same view, the `get` route doesn't define `$users`

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::get('/students',[UsersController::class,'view']);
```

you're existing get route is literally only returning a view and nothing else so of course $users isn't defined

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it.

```
public function search(Request $request){
   $query = Students::where('name','LIKE','%'.$request->search.'%')->get();
   return view('index',['students' => $query]);
}
```

in the Route

```
use App\Http\Controllers\StudentController;

Route::get('/',function(){
  return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/'[StudentController::class,'search']);
``
in view at view/welcome.blade.php
```

It tells me that $students is undefined. How do I pass the variable in the route?

```
@foreach($students as $student)
   {{$tudent->id}}
   {{$student->name}}
   {{$student->email}}
@endforeach
```